# Slide element up/down and collapse at a certain point?

Tags: jquery, css

How replicate this effect.

An effect similar to `slideUp()`. I want the element to animate moving up/down but once it reaches a certain point to start collapsing.

Here is an [example](http://infographic.arte.tv/cinema/polar/fr/femme-fatale#/presentation).

When you click "enter" the words "La femme fatale" slide up/down and collapse as they go past a certain point.

I intend to use jQuery animate with css.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or describe a technique (*"point you in the right direction"*) or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a combination of CSS and JavaScript. You need JavaScript to trigger the click and then can go on with CSS `transition` and `transform`:

jQuery:

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    $('p').addClass('reduced');
});
```

CSS:

```
div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  transition: transform 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1) 500ms;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}

div:first-child p.reduced {
  transform: translate(0px, 100px);
}

div:nth-child(2) p.reduced {
  transform: translate(0px, -100px);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>Femme</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>fatale</p>
</div>

<button>Click</button>
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfyb1dbk/)

Comment: That's beautiful thank you. Interestingly when I try your example in JSFiddle in safari it doesn't work. Is that just a JSFiddle issue or is there something here that doesn't work within safari? Thanks.

Comment: In the current version of Safari (9.0.2) I have no problem with the fiddle.

Comment: Cool ok, must be a problem on my end. Thanks again.